# How to assign a map with all the attributes & values from Properties step in SoapUI using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Here is what I am trying to do:

Step1: Properties  (10)  //containing 10 attributes with corresponding values of different types - numeric, string, and Boolean

Now, I am trying to load those attributes into a Map object in my groovy script , is this how I should be defining the map to put all the attributes with their values in?

```
Map attributes =  messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").getProperties()
```

then I want to loop through above map and validate against a json response , for example :

```
attributes.each{key, value-> 
      def expected = ${value}
      verifyValues(json_response, key, expected)
}
```

=================More to the problem===================

Here is my property step containing some sample values:

fields   values

porp1 : 12

prop2 : true

prop3 : abc.com, xyz.info

I wanted to know if this is the right way to get all those above properties in a map which can be later used to validate against a json-response?

```
Map attributes =  messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").getProperties()
```

if I see values I get by commenting the validation method then it gives me this outcome:

```
  attributes.each{key, value-> 
      def expected = value.getValue()
      println expected
      //verifyValues(json_response, key, expected)
}


   Script Assertion Passed: 
   [{prop1=com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.XmlBeansPropertiesTestPropertyHolder$PropertiesStepProperty@8f03928,
```

prop2=com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.XmlBeansPropertiesTestPropertyHolder$PropertiesStepProperty@44c2146c,

```
prop3=com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.XmlBeansPropertiesTestPropertyHolder$PropertiesStepProperty@58ed0593}]
```

Comment: Instead of property step, you may use property file itself(one step less) and read it in `script assertion`.

Comment: Yes, I could but I wanted to keep all the values in the test itself. So that I do not have carry the files with the test, right?

Comment: Ok. May be what you might interested in is to cast the type, right? You might know what property is of what type, based on that the property value needs be parsed.

Comment: Thanks Rao! I have added an example of my properties. Would that give you any idea what I'm trying to do using above example? Your suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: That is fine. What exactly the issue being faced? any stack trace or error ?

Comment: I get a small pop-up message with "Text must not be null" in SoapUI script window

Comment: I fixed "Text must not be null" message but found that I'm not able to read the actual values of the attributes rather it's giving those field reference(pls see edited questions.

Comment: If I read using  '  log.info(expected)'  it returns value. I would appreciate if someone can explain why     'println expected' cannot do the same?

Comment: `print` would log the statement into soapui's log files.

Comment: Are you still looking for answer? Where have you stuck?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Do you mean I should check soapui log file for the output of my println statement?

Comment: Yes. And what exactly the issue that is being faced?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was actually debuging my code by adding "println expected_value" in the above posted to check if i have assigned the attributes to a map correctly or not. Since I was not seeing actual value as output so thinking my assignment was not write. Hope that explains mybproblem.  My map assignment is actually is doing what I was expecting.  So Im good here. Thanks again!